# Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. After I created the procedure, I selected the option to "Script Table AS EXECUTE", which (after entering the `SELECT` queries for the field names) comes up as:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @tablename varchar(50)
DECLARE @field1 varchar(25)
DECLARE @field2 varchar(25)

SELECT @tablename = '[databasename].[dbo].[tablename]'
SELECT @field1 = 'name'
SELECT @field2 = 'amount'

EXECUTE @RC = [databasename].[dbo].[procedurename] 
   @tablename
  ,@field1
  ,@field2
GO
```

I then get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'

but there doesn't appear to be any '.' anywhere near line 1 or anywhere other than the table names?

Comment: I'll bet the error is in the procedure itself. Based on what little has been posted so far I would guess that dynamic SQL is being used... **YUCK!** Please post the contents of the procedure itself.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. You can't execute a table. The code you posted looks exceptionally dangerous. What are you really trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange . . . The code is executing a procedure.  The table name is the first argument.

Comment: Guess I got confused by the statement from the OP "Script Table AS EXECUTE", that must have been script proc as...

Comment: @SeanLange yes sorry. Script proc as

Comment: It must be a syntax error within [procedurename].  Your script runs just fine otherwise: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a64dc/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with that code. As it stated in the comment that something is wrong with your stored procedure. Take the source code of the procedure, delete lines with create/alter and the input parameters until the first begin. After that remove the last END. Replace all the parameters in the code and execute it as normal TSQL statement. In that case you'll easily find where it is failing.

Just to be sure that your code is working, execute following script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [procedurename]
@tablename VARCHAR(1000)
  ,@field1 VARCHAR(1000)
  ,@field2 VARCHAR(1000)
AS  
BEGIN
SELECT 1
END   
GO

DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @tablename varchar(50)
DECLARE @field1 varchar(25)
DECLARE @field2 varchar(25)

SELECT @tablename = '[databasename].[dbo].[tablename]'
SELECT @field1 = 'name'
SELECT @field2 = 'amount'



EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[procedurename] 
   @tablename
  ,@field1
  ,@field2

GO
DROP PROCEDURE [procedurename]
GO
```

Comment: Thanks I am working on fixing the code and then I will test this out